# Excel-VBA ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Name not linking to cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Below are two examples for creating a name of a new series:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='GSI with DSPV Data'!$BUX$4" 

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = Worksheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(nameRow, nameCol)
```

`nameRow` and `nameCol` can be set to the same values as column: BUX and row: 4 in this instance. In both cases, the legend correctly displays the new series name. However, the second example doesn't link the cell to the series name gui edit box. The series name box remains blank.

The first example is not useful to me as I need to represent the cell using variables for the column and row, as this is within an iterative For loop.

Please see below for my full code:

```
Sub ExtendPlot()

Dim nameRow As Integer
Dim nameCol As Integer
Dim maxPlotRow As Integer
Dim xPlotCol As Integer
Dim minPlotRow As Integer
Dim yPlotCol As Integer
Dim xValues As Range
Dim yValues As Range

nameRow = 4 'the series name is always on the same row
minPlotRow = 2 'the minimum plotted row is always 2
maxPlotRow = 400 'the maximum plotted row is always 400
nameCol = Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Columns("BUX").Column 'specify the column of the series name location and turn this into an integer
xPlotCol = Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Columns("BUY").Column 'specify the column of the series x values location and turn this into an integer
yPlotCol = Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Columns("BUZ").Column 'specify the column of the series y values location and turn this into an integer
Set xValues = Range(Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(minPlotRow, xPlotCol), Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(maxPlotRow, xPlotCol)) 'set the range of the x axis given the above values
Set yValues = Range(Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(minPlotRow, yPlotCol), Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(maxPlotRow, yPlotCol)) 'set the range of the y axis given the above values
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries 'create a new series on the current graph
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='GSI with DSPV Data'!$BUX$4" 'create the name for the new series by linking to the reference cell
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).xValues = xValues 'create the x axis by linking to the x axis range
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = yValues 'create the y axis by linking to the y axis range

For i = 2 To 30 'start a For loop for the next coming series
nameCol = nameCol + 8 'the name of the next series is always located 8 columns later than the first
xPlotCol = xPlotCol + 8 'the x axis values of the next series are always located 8 columns later than the first
yPlotCol = yPlotCol + 8 'the y axis values of the next series are always located 8 columns later than the first
Set xValues = Range(Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(minPlotRow, xPlotCol), Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(maxPlotRow, xPlotCol)) 'set the range of the x axis given the above values
Set yValues = Range(Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(minPlotRow, yPlotCol), Sheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(maxPlotRow, yPlotCol)) 'set the range of the y axis given the above values

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = Worksheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(nameRow, nameCol) 'create the name for the new series by linking to the reference cell
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).xValues = xValues 'create the x axis by linking to the x axis range
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = yValues 'create the y axis by linking to the y axis range
Next i

End Sub
```

I have used separate ranges for the x axis and y axis on purpose, such that people with zero VBA experience can picture exactly what's going on here. It is not that computational exhaustive (I don't think?) to do this. It just doesn't look very neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying it in the method below:

```
Dim nameRow As Long, NameCol As String
Dim SerTitleNameRng As Range

NameCol = "BUX"
nameRow = 4

With Worksheets("GSI with DSPV Data")
    Set SerTitleNameRng = .Cells(nameRow, NameCol)
End With

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & SerTitleNameRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I implemented what you suggested and it worked.

One thing though, I don't see the need for the With loop? What's the point of that?

Comment: @MichaelWhitaker  just my style of coding , you can get rid of it

Comment: Fair enough indeed. Thanks very much for the help Re this. 

Do you have any idea why this is necessary though?
 For example, why should:

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = Worksheets("GSI with DSPV Data").Cells(nameRow, nameCol) 

not work? I remember being told that this type of command does not select the Header, and thus doesn't work. I am not totally sure what this means however?